Any operation in remote docker context fails, while ssh works fine
On my local machine I am trying to use a docker context on a remote server like this:
sudo docker context create contextName --docker "host=ssh://user@domain"
sudo docker context use contextName

But when I try to do anything with this context, I get a Permission denied (publickey) Error:
$ sudo docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    26.1.3
 Context:    steste
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.14.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.27.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.45/info": command 
[ssh -o ConnectTimeout=30 -l user -- domain docker system dial-stdio] has exited 
with exit status 255, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or 
later is installed on the remote host: stderr=user@domain: 
Permission denied (publickey).


$ sudo docker ps
error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.45/containers/json": 
command [ssh -o ConnectTimeout=30 -l user -- domain docker system dial-stdio] 
has exited with exit status 255, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 
18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=user@domain: 
Permission denied (publickey).

However, connecting via ssh to the server works fine and docker is up and running on that system:
$ ssh user@domain
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64)
...

user@domain:~$ docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    26.1.3
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.14.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.27.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.23.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 26.1.3
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8b3b7ca2e5ce38e8f31a34f35b2b68ceb8470d89
 runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-107-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.751GiB
 Name: steste.eu
 ID: 4d9da92f-ea7c-47a4-8679-adb859c35528
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

The user on the server is part of the docker group and can run docker commands without sudo.
I found two related seeming questions on forum.docker.com, but in one instance the issue only occurred intermittently and was caused by rate limiting, and in the other, the ssh key was in a non-standard location.
My ed25519 key pair is in ~/.ssh. Is it possible that docker does not find them there?

If you want the docker client to make use your ssh configuration, you need to stop prefixing it with sudo. That makes it run as root, and it will be using root's ssh configuration.

Thank you, that makes sense. I've added my local user to the docker group and now it works. I guess alternatives would be to symlink my key pair in root's .ssh or to use rootless mode then?

You don't need to symlink your keys into root's .ssh directory, and you don't need to add your local user to the docker group: you're not interacting with /var/run/docker.sock; you're interacting with a remote system via ssh. Your local permissions aren't germane.
